# Are there any tools to extract basic blocks and CFG (Control Flow Graph) from executable files

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I'm working on source code control flow obfuscation in native code such as `C/C++`. I'm researching on some techniques which do it and resulting spaghetti code.

But we want to evaluate compiled file and compare the original one with equivalent obfuscated one. is there any tools to help us?

there is some tools such as [Underestand](http://www.scitools.com/) that extracts `CFG` from source code but we want extract `CFG` from `.exe` file.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you compile it yourself? In that case, gcov related information might be useful.

Comment: Yes, I compile them (orginal code & obfuscated code). and i want to extract CFG and compare them.

Comment: Note that the CFG for a compiled program in general isn't the same as the CFG of your source code. For instance, the linker will replace single nodes representing library calls by their actual implementations, which usually form more than a single node.

Comment: @MSalters I know the basic blocks in compiled program differs from the source code's. It's ok.

simply i'm looking for a tool that does gather the branches of whole of the machine code and consequently specify basic blocks from those.

Comment: @AliAdl: Exactly how are you going to extract the CFG for a virtual call? That's resolved at runtime, and in general undecidable. Ideal for control flow obfuscuation, so quite relevant here. Similarly, exceptions in table-driven exception mechanisms add invisible code paths.

Comment: @MSalters in generally we can ignore external function calls and treat with them as simple(non-branch) instructions.

Comment: You could customize your compiler, e.g. using your [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/); of course this supposes that you are compiling your application from source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a plugin for [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) or [Pin](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) to analyze your program statically or dynamically respectively, to create a CFG.

Comment: Do you have any practical experience?

Comment: Yes, I have practical experience.

Comment: A combination of IDA Pro and possibly [bindiff](http://www.zynamics.com/bindiff.html) sounds like what you want

Comment: @pank4j, could u let me know how am I gona be able to batch output the subroutine graphs in Ida Pro? my question is here : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619663/ida-pro-gragh-output-batch-mode`